# Difference between Mercury Sable driver's doors?

Tags: door, mercury, sable

Need to replace 1998 Mercury Sable driver's door with used part. Is there a difference between Taurus/Sable driver's doors manufactured before and after March 31, 1998?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Since the model ran through 1999, I'm doubting there was any major change in the door shell in 1998. Are you seeing something somewhere which states differently?

Comment: When I search for the part at online used auto parts sites i found sometimes that inquiry asks if the car was manufactured before or after March of 1998.

Comment: Gotcha. So long as you align your needs with the donor car, you shouldn't have an issue. Manufacturers sometimes have small changes in fitment and what have you because of design flaws or the need to update. The overall design and shape doesn't change, but it makes a difference for other reasons. This may be the case here. I can't tell you for sure, though, but like I said, just align the dates between your car and the donor and there should be no issues.